# How can i insert the data in one schema table to another schema table?

Tags: oracle

I have two different schemas. Each schema contains different tables. For example a is a table in schema1 and b is table in schema2. Now i want to insert table a data into table b(schema2).

Comment: `schema_name.table_name` would give you complete freedom to access across schemas. (Provided same database, unless you have a db-link)

Answer (score 6):

Login to the user which have access to both the schema and run insert command like,

```
INSERT INTO schema1.table_name 
     SELECT * FROM schema2.table_name;
```

Assuming that the tables are identical in both the schema.

Answer (score 3):

schema1 needs privileges on table in schema2

```
connect schema2

grant select , insert on b to schema1;
```

Then

```
connect schema1

insert into schema2.b select * from a;
```

Or create a synonym

```
create synonym b for schema2.b;

insert into b select * from a;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert in other schema in any database.
first of all table needs to be created.
below query will help you to build and copy data from one schema to another.

below will create table only DDL.

CREATE TABLE  Destinationschemaname.tablename
 AS  SELECT * FROM sourceschemaname.tablename where 1 =2;

then DML
Insert into Destinationschemaname.tablename 
SELECT * FROM sourceschemaname.tablename;

```
                  (OR)
```

below will copy complete table DDL and DML
CREATE TABLE  Destinationschemaname.tablename 
AS  SELECT * FROM sourceschemaname.tablename;